# Libgit2Sharp: Get the list of files between two tags

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp

We have a Git bash command  given below which gets the list of committed files between 2 tags in github,

```
git log tag1 tag2 --stat
```

Could anyone provide the equivalent Libgit2Sharp code for it?

Answer (score 2):

try this: `git log tag1 tag2 --stat`

```
        using (var repo = new Repository(@"repoPath"))
        {
            Tag tagTo  = repo.Tags["tag2"];
            Tag tagFrom  = repo.Tags["tag1"];

            var commitFrom = repo.Lookup<LibGit2Sharp.Commit>(tagFrom.Target.Sha);
            var commitTo = repo.Lookup<LibGit2Sharp.Commit>(tagTo.Target.Sha);

            TreeChanges treeChanges = repo.Diff.Compare<TreeChanges>(commitFrom.Tree, commitTo.Tree);
        }
```

But when you want only commits between tags: `git log tag1 tag2` you can use:

```
        using (var repo = new Repository(@"repoPath"))
        {
            Tag tagTo  = repo.Tags["tag2"];
            Tag tagFrom  = repo.Tags["tag1"];

            var filter = new CommitFilter();

            filter.IncludeReachableFrom = tagTo.Target.Sha;
            filter.ExcludeReachableFrom = tagFrom.Target.Sha;

            var commits = repo.Commits.QueryBy(filter).ToList();
        }
```